# Create objective-c wrapper for .dylib file

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, wrapper, dylib

I have paid for an expensive .dylib file however, the code is non objective-c in short, horrendous! I am thinking of creating a wrapper of some sort like an API to make interfacing with this `.dylib` nightmare free. How is this done? Here is what I was going to do:

Create a `customDylibSDKWrapper` `.h` and `.m` file, and have the appropriate function names that will keep things simple, and in the `.m` file, add all the c++ functions inside each objective-c function. So then all I would need to do in the future is, call the objective-c function and that will automatically call the C++ code.

Is this the correct way of creating a wrapper?

If it is, this does not create a private hidden wrapper, all the code will still be visibile. Is there anyway to package the `.dylib` file along with my objective-c `.m` files exposing only the objective-c `.h` file?

If anyone is curious to see the horrendous code feel free to look at this link: [link to hard to decipher code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388684/just-paid-1000-for-a-mac-based-finger-print-sdk-and-its-not-what-i-expected?noredirect=1#comment34038191_22388684)

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way of creating a wrapper.  But I don't understand what you mean about private stuff and packing the `.m` that you wrote into the `.dylib` and only exposing the `.h` file.  :/  All the ObjC wrappers for C/C++ libraries I've seen have the `.m` exposed.

Comment: I guess what I am asking for is if there's a way to create my own private `dylib`, `framework` or whatever, something that packages my code into something more isolated just like the original c++ `dylib` file is hidden leaving only the header files that came with it for me to see, the source files are packaged inside all encrypted. So I'd like to enclose the original dylib that I am creating a wrapper for, along with my source files that make up my wrapper, leaving only my header file that will let users know how to interface with my wrapper.

Answer (score 4):

You can create both a dynamic library and a static library with Xcode.

Creating dynamic libraries isn't officially supported, and it requires editing some XML, and apps that include dynamic libraries won't be approved by Apple, so I'm not going to bother with dynamic libraries in this answer.

You can however easily create static libraries.

Step one: start a new project, being sure to select Cocoa Touch Static Library when you create the project:

[image]

Step two: Write your code.

Step three: Push the run button.  Since your static library should have any code that will actually run, nothing should actually run.  Instead, Xcode builds the library.

In the view on the left that shows all your folders and files and such, you should see a `.a` file, which is the compiled library.  You can find on your computer by right-clicking and clicking "Show in Finder".

Now all that's left is distributing the `.h`/`.a` files to whoever you want.

Comment: Will this also bundle the .dylib that I originally am creating the wrapper for inside the .a file?